# Vertx Zipkin tracing not working from JAR

Tags: vert.x, zipkin

I recently added Zipkin tracing to our Vert.x service, version 4.2.1, as per https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-zipkin/java. When I run/debug the service from IntelliJ with server class, I saw tracing logs being generated in our tracing tool. For deployment, we make a fat JAR file using Maven shade plugin, with Vert.x Launcher and server class in manifest. When I run JAR file with "java -jar servier.jar", there's no more tracing logs being sent to the tracing tool. Does anyone have the similar issue before? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is due to the fat JAR build process. You must merge Java service files.

This is how to configure the Maven Shade Plugin:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Otherwise you can use the Vert.x Maven Plugin instead. It build the FAT Jar and more.

Comment: I tried Vert.x Maven Plugin and it's same as Maven Shade Plugin. I turned to use Opentelemetry Java agent. Thanks!